# Does angularjs gets loaded on fallback of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In the below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Falback procedure</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined')
                document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../localfolder/jquery.js"></script>');
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

considering a scenario, where google CDN has reach-ability issues that triggers fallback mechanism of loading local jQuery library(sitting in webserver).

In such scenario, Does angularjs library get loaded? after executing `document.write`

Comment: Why wouldn't it be loaded?

Comment: `Angularjs` and `jquery` are getting loaded from different `CDNs` and `AngularJs` does not need `jquery.js` to work or better to say `AngularJs` isnt dependent on `jquery.js`..

Comment: If your question is about whether the `document.write()` call will be a problem, the answer is **no**.

Comment: @Pointy I was wondering, whether `document.write` was an asynchronous execution, that cannot block scripts below the page.

Comment: @overexchange no, it is not. It will add the `<script>` tag immediately, and then the very next thing the browser does will be to load that script (jQuery, from your server) and evaluate it. Then it will move on to the Angular import.

Comment: @Pointy OK I got the answer

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems with that code that are likely to be making it not behave as you expect:

1. You have a literal `</script>` **inside** a script block. It doesn't matter that it's inside a string, it terminates the block it's in. You have to break it up so the browser doesn't see it as the end of the block:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined')
           document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../localfolder/jquery.js"><\/script>');
           // Note the \------------------------------------------------------------------^
   </script>
   ```

   The `\` there is meaningless in JavaScript, but prevents the browser from seeing `</script>` and thus from ending the script block prematurely. Other ways you see it done are `'....<' + '/script>'` or `'...</scr' + 'ipt>'`, etc.
2. Your `src` on the Angular script is incorrect, so it won't work whether jQuery loads or not (or from where). You've made the URL relative to the path of the page, but you need to make it at *least* protocol-relative by adding `//`:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.js">
   </script>
   <!-- here --------------------------^ -->
   ```

In a comment, you asked

> I was wondering, whether `document.write` was an asynchronous execution

No, it happens immediately when the function is run. In your case, since the function is at the top level of a `script` tag with no special attributes, the HTML parser has to screech to a halt and run that JavaScript code, processing any tokens the JavaScript code outputs via `document.write`, and waiting until the JavaScript code finishes before moving on to the Angular part.

The browser may well be able to scan ahead to preload the `angular.js` file, but it won't *execute* the contents of that file until the parser has reached that file's `script` tag, because the order in which scripts execute is well-defined (e.g., in document order) unless you use the `async` or `defer` attributes.